# how to connect to document content server or repository using opencmis

Tags: documentum, opencmis, documentum6.5, webtop

I tried to connect to Documentum content server repository using cmis API, but I am not able to connect.

I have Documentum content server & web top application, Now I just want to connect to repository, and I need repository session.

How to connect to documentum repository using CMIS API?

I tried to use following code, but its not working because Its a code snipet which I used for connecting Alfresco repository, and I just modified same with Documentum server IP.

So any sample code will be really helpful, At list If I can get repository session object, It would be great.

```
SessionFactory factory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
        Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // user credentials
        parameter.put(SessionParameter.USER, "user");
        parameter.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, "pass");

        // Uncomment for Atom Pub binding

        parameter.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, "http://localhost:8080//cmis/atom");

        // Uncomment for Atom Pub binding
        parameter.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
        parameter.put(SessionParameter.AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDER_CLASS,
                CmisBindingFactory.NTLM_AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDER);

        List<Repository> repositories = factory.getRepositories(parameter);
        sourceSession = repositories.get(0).createSession();
```

With above code I am not able to get repository session, so please let me know if I am doing anything wrong, or please share any other sample code if you have.

I used above code to get Alfresco repository session, But I am not familiar with documentum, So I tried with modifying same alfresco cmis code.

Comment: So that this wouldn't be too easy, you decided that "some error" is good enough description?

Comment: @JamesZ I don't know whether the code I have used is correct or not, as I mentioned I don't have any Idea at documentum side, I am having experties at Alfresco end. That's the reason Asked for some code sample. If you need stack trace of error which I am getting, then I can share it, but I don't think It will useful...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, avoid NTLM! Even if you get it working at some point, you will run into strange issues later.

This document is a bit outdated, but maybe it contains a few clues for you: http://www.jouvinio.net/wiki/images/a/a4/Documentum_cmis_6.7_deployment.pdf